# Change Screen Colors

Tags: interface, customization, theme

Can the program default colors be changed, that is the grey menu and screen itself.

I simply cannot see properly with the dull grey colors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.
Enter the blender user preferences<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> Add go into the themes tab.
In side the themes tab you can customize all the colors.
[image]
When You are done, be sure to hit **Save User Settings.**

You can also **Down Load Themes:**

You can download themes for site such as [blendswap](http://www.blendswap.com/category/blender-themes), or by searching on the internet.
To install a theme, press install theme, and then open your theme, which should be a .xml file.

Then save your settings.
[image]